# Does the monk's Step of the Wind feature activate the benefit of the Mobile feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, movement, monk, actions

The [Mobile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/mobile) feat (PHB, p. 168) says:

> When you use the Dash action, difficult terrain doesn't cost you extra movement on that turn

The monk's [Step of the Wind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#Ki-228) feature says:

> You can spend 1 ki point to take the Disengage or Dash action as a bonus action on your turn...

Due to the wording here, would that mean that if a Monk with the Mobile feat uses Step of the Wind to Dash, are they not affected by difficult terrain?

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. I have made an edit to try to make the question a bit more organized but feel free to rollback or [edit] the changes if you don't like anything. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes

When you spend a ki point on Step of the Wind (and choose to Dash) you're taking the actual Dash action (as a bonus action). Since Mobile's effect applies to when you take the Dash action, Step of the Wind's Dash would mean difficult terrain doesn't cost you extra movement for that turn.